# Check Java String containing one alpha & numeric characters and one of these special characters(@, #,$)

Tags: java, apache-commons

Hi i want to check whether a string contains one alpha, one numeric and at least one of these  special characters(@, #,$). So could anyone please guide me to resolve the issue.

Note : I have apache common lang 3.0 library. It will  help us to resolve the above issue?

Comment: read on regEx or at least google for contains method in String. What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation.

```
private static boolean isValidPassword(char[] password) {
    boolean hasLetter = false, hasDigit = false, hasSpecial = false;
    for (char ch : password)
        if (Character.isLetter(ch))
            hasLetter = true;
        else if (Character.isDigit(ch))
            hasDigit = true;
        else if ("@#$".indexOf(ch) != -1)
            hasSpecial = true;
    return (hasLetter && hasDigit && hasSpecial);
}
```

I can be adjusted as need for exact definition of "letter", "digit", and "special", and to stop searching early when all 3 found, if needed.

Comment: Thank you Andreas. It is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using String.matches() and using a regex. Consider Following Solution.

```
public boolean isAlphaNumeric(String s){
String pattern= "^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$*()_+])[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d!@#$*()_+]";
    if(s.matches(pattern)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

}

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Not working. It is not allowing other special characters.Also if your string contains only "ganesh" it's true but it should return false. For my case string should contain atleast one numeric & special characters($,@,#).